# Increase shipping rate by sets

Tags: php, function

I have a few shipping zones and some shipping classes set up in WooCommerce. I am trying to pull the value that has been inputted into a shipping class for a particular zone and have it output based on a number of items per set.

For example:

- Zone: Test2
- Shipping class: 50_zone_shipping
- 50_zone_shipping value: $10
- Items per set: 5

Test2 (zone) has a shipping class of '50_zone_shipping', and that shipping class has a value of $10. Items per set for that shipping class is 5 items. So for every item up to 5 items, the shipping cost should be increased by 10. Customer buys 1-5 items, they would be charged $10 for shipping. If they buy 6-10 items they would be charged $20 for shipping and so on etc.

I have manage to accomplish each part of this with two different sets of code but can't get it to all work in one.

This first code set will increase the shipping cost in the right way by quantity and 'Items per set', however the shipping cost is not pulled in dynamically from the shipping class like I need. So I am not able to target the shipping classes that I want:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_class_quantity_based_shipping_cost', 10, 2);
function custom_shipping_class_quantity_based_shipping_cost($rates, $package) {
    $target_shipping_class = '50_zone_shipping';
    $item_count = 0;

    // Calculate the total quantity of items in the target shipping class in the cart
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if ($cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $target_shipping_class) {
            $item_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    $items_per_set = 5;
    $shipping_cost_per_set = 10.00; // Default value if the shipping class cost is not set

    // Get the shipping class cost from the shipping class object
    $shipping_classes = WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_classes();

    
    if (!empty($shipping_classes) && isset($shipping_classes[$target_shipping_class])) {
        $shipping_class = $shipping_classes[$target_shipping_class];
        $shipping_class_cost = WC_Shipping::parse_cost($shipping_class->cost);

        if (is_numeric($shipping_class_cost)) {
            $shipping_cost_per_set = $shipping_class_cost;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the number of sets and adjust the shipping cost
    $sets = ceil($item_count / $items_per_set);
    $shipping_cost = $sets * $shipping_cost_per_set;

    // Update the shipping cost for each rate
    foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $shipping_cost;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

So I came up with the following solution:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_class_quantity_based_shipping_cost', 10, 2);

    function custom_shipping_class_quantity_based_shipping_cost($rates, $package) {
        $target_shipping_class = '50_zone_shipping'; 
        $item_count = 0;
    
        // Calculate the total quantity of items in the target shipping class in the cart
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            if ($cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $target_shipping_class) {
                $item_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }
    
        // Get the shipping classes
        $shipping_classes = WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_classes();
    
        // Check if the target shipping class exists in the shipping classes and get its cost
        if (!empty($shipping_classes) && isset($shipping_classes[$target_shipping_class])) {
            $class_cost_string = $shipping_classes[$target_shipping_class]->cost;
            $class_cost = WC_Shipping::parse_cost($class_cost_string);
    
            // Calculate the number of sets and the shipping cost for each set
            $items_per_set = 5;
            $sets = ceil($item_count / $items_per_set);
            $shipping_cost_per_set = $class_cost * $items_per_set;
    
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on the number of sets purchased
            $shipping_cost = $sets * $shipping_cost_per_set;
    
            // Update the shipping cost for the target shipping class
            foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
                if ($rate->method_id === 'flat_rate' && $rate->instance_id === 'Test2') {
                    $rate->cost = $shipping_cost;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        return $rates;
    }
```

However, now the quantity does not follow the 'Items per set' rules I have set in place. It will pull from the correct zone and shipping class but ignores the 'Items per set' condition. I'm sure the answer is somewhere between the two but I'm not seeing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.